# Have trouble creating a bar graph with ggplot with having both x and y variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble creating a bar graph using ggplot with both x and y variables. I also would like to have two bins (before and after acceleration) for each letter on the x-axis to enable comparison of before and after results. However, I am getting an error message stating that the "Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic".

```
DF4 <- data.frame(DF1$Avg_Acceleration, DF3$Avg_Acceleration2)
DF4$Names <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
DF5 <- DF4 %>% gather(Before_After, Acceleration, DF1.Avg_Acceleration, 
DF3.Avg_Acceleration2) %>% group_by(Names)
DF5$Before_After <- as.factor(DF5$Before_After)
DF5$Names <- as.factor(DF5$Names)
(g2 <- ggplot(DF5) + geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=Names, y= Acceleration, fill= 
Before_After), position="dodge"))
```

Comment: It's a little hard to read the code, one thing that would help is if you would make a very simple example, possibly using some sample data.  From what I can tell you need 2 numeric variables, a "name" variable that is some kind of grouping and then a second factor with two values.  Is that right?

Comment: Also try switching to geom_col() which can accept a y value.

Comment: Aye. `?geom_col`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you don't provide sample data but like the error says you need to set your `stat` to `"identity"` not `"count"`. You can always use `geom_col()` as suggested by some of the comments. 
 You would do something like:

```
DF4 <- data.frame(DF1$Avg_Acceleration, DF3$Avg_Acceleration2)
DF4$Names <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
DF5 <- DF4 %>% gather(Before_After, Acceleration, DF1.Avg_Acceleration, 
DF3.Avg_Acceleration2) %>% group_by(Names)
DF5$Before_After <- as.factor(DF5$Before_After)
DF5$Names <- as.factor(DF5$Names)
(g2 <- ggplot(DF5) + geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=Names, y= Acceleration,,stat="identity",fill= 
Before_After), position="dodge"))
```